# Can I safely trigger a Speedotron D1204LV power pack with a Pocket Wizard Plus III?

Tags: studio-lighting, wireless-triggers

I recently acquired some 10+ year-old studio strobes, the Speedotron D1204LV with four heads.

On the power pack is a sticker indicating that the trigger voltage is 6 volts.

I'm interested in getting some Pocket Wizard Plus III's to use with this kit. However, I think based on the [spec page](http://www.pocketwizard.com/products/transmitter_receiver/36/PW-PLUS3/spec/) that the Pocket Wizard can only trigger up to 3 volts.

Is this correct? If so, what do I need to make it compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the title question, yes, the Plus IIIs can handle up to 300 volts of trigger voltage on the flash it's hooked up to (that's listed as the "Max Sync Port Voltage" on the spec sheet), so they're definitely safe with your D1204LV (as well as any older model of Speedotron generator that doesn't have the "LV" in the model name). The 3 volts mentioned on the spec sheet is the voltage present on the unit's hot shoe, so when it's mounted on a camera, the *camera* only sees a 3 volt trigger voltage. That means it's safe to use with all current-model and older cameras.